# Lowest Common Factor

Tags: c, algorithm

Can anyone suggest some fast ways to calculate the lowest common factor(excluding 1) of given two numbers?
One way could be checking if GCD(a,b)>1, prime factorizing(a and b), and choosing the smallest common prime factor as result.

Is their a better way to do this?

Example : LCF(20,30)=2 , LCF(13,39)=13

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: There's probably a million (exaggeration?...) resources on the web covering this topic! Please show what you have tried. SO isn't here to "do things for you"...

Comment: @unwind No its not a homework. I have tried doing it by quadratic seive. The question is about doing it better?

Comment: @ElRonnoco I already mentioned one approach in the problem. I was expecting to improve its complexity.

Comment: Not sure if I misinterpret your algorithm. But if `g = gcd(a,b) > 1`, you want to find the smallest prime factor of `g`, not to factorise `a` and `b` individually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I don't think you will find anything better than trying to divide both numbers by the prime numbers until you find some that divides both or reaches `sqrt(min(a,b))`

Comment: You get a better worst-case behaviour if you first calculate `g = gcd(a,b)` and then search for the smallest prime factor of `g`.

Comment: @Daniel, that's right for the worst case, but for the average case, given two random numbers, statistically, it is quite probably than the lcd is a small number. So the dumb divide-by-primes method will find it faster than just calculating the gcd alone quite frequently. Maybe an hybrid solution, that first checks for 2, 3 and 5 (36% of the cases) and then switches to calculating the gcd and finding its smaller divisor (starting at 7) would be the best solution.

Comment: I don't think that's quite correct, there's also a good chance that the GCD will be 1, and that totally ruins the way ignoring the GCD. I too think that (unless you have particular restrictions on the input, e.g. no prime factors < 100) the hybrid, first checking a couple of small primes and then doing the GCD will be fastest on average.

Comment: You are right, I overlooked the case where gcd == 1 that seems to account for 60% of the cases.

Answer (score -1):

Just loop from 2 to the value n/2 where n is the smaller of the two numbers. Put the condition in the loop as given
for(int i=2;i<=n/2;i++)
if(n%i==0 && m%i==0)break;

i is your required value.